# User with "Full Control" can't create folders in a document library!

Tags: document-library, permissions

My users with "Full Control" don't have all the options one would expect.  For example, they cannot create a new folder in a document Library.  They are members of a group of "Site Owners".  I have verified the permissions for that group, and ensured that they are not somewhere that has unique permissions.  Any ideas out there?

Comment: Pleaes check whether the option 'Make _New Folder" command available?_ is set to _Yes_ in _Library Settings >> Advanced Settings_.

Comment: What solution you got can you please share ?